# Adding video to an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

How do I add a video to an iPhone app. using iPhone SDK 3.2.5?
I dont see the actual video but I can hear it playing.

Here is the code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Facebook" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you have so far and that doesn't work?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov This is the code I used: -(void) viewDidLoad{
NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
 [theMovie play]; [super viewDidLoad]; }

Comment: @Shuqom, please update your answer with properly formatting the code. Don't use the comments section for code because it is unreadable.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov
I have added the code in the questions sections and I hope it is readable :)

Comment: @Shuqom, great, now it's much better. Thank you.

Comment: Why all the negative votes guys? Come on. He is just looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the frame for you MPMoviePlayerController and add it to your view:

```
theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0);
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

Answer (score 2):

First off – find out what video format you are having. I assume it's not the one supported by iPhones.

1. So when you learn this you can go ahead and look for a third party player that is able to play back your video. I'm sure there are a lot of them there. Recommendation from me – try using VLC.
2. If you want to use default videos app on your iPhone (which, of course, is way better than any other alternative) you can try out Windows & Mac application WALTR 2: https://softorino.com/waltr/windows-guides/how-transfer-videos-to-iphone-without-itunes. It adapts any video & music for iPhone playback and pushes them to your default app on an iPhone.